# When I change the texture (same path) it load the first load

Tags: three.js, textures

I can change texture image of a object with different path using

```
 //create textureMaterial
function CreateTextureMaterial(ImageName){
    var Texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture/'+ImageName); 
    var Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
    map:Texture});
    return Material;
}
//change Texture
function ChangeTexture(ObjectName, TextureMaterial){
    obj = view3D.scene.getObjectByName(ObjectName);
    obj.material = TextureMaterial;
    //if render bad(wrong uvmap) use obj.material.materials[number]
}
```

in my site the user load an image and it is stored always with the same path (example `texture/usertexture.jpg`) and the program load the the image when I change from the default

`ChangeTexture(ObjectName,CreateTextureMaterial(path))`

But if I change the image (the path is always the same) and I call the same function

```
$('element').load('page.php',ChangeTexture(ObjectName,CreateTextureMaterial(path))
```

It loads the first image and not the updated one...

I think it does it because it is memorized somewhere in the browser so... Where I can find it and remove it from memory?

I have already checked the cache but it is free...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, i try to change the texture with image captured from a cropper canvas (like https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) and i use the image directly to the object, instead saving it on the server and use the new image stored whith var Texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture/'+ImageName);

i get the output data directly and put it in the texture

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture();
texture.image = result;
texture.needsUpdate = true;
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
map:texture});
var obj = scene.getObjectByName('myobject');
obj.material.materials[0] = material;
```

where result is the image (something like "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...")
if it doesn't work is possibly you need to use the result with method `result.toDataURL`

Comment: A different solution to prevent browser caching when the path to the texture image is the same is the answer in this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750463/angular-or-three-js-not-pulling-image-from-server-but-rather-browser-cache). You can just add a random parameter to the image URL when passing it to the loader to make the URL different and avoid load from cache.

Answer (score 0):

Before reloading a texture try to run this code:

```
THREE.Cache.remove(url);
```

Where the `url` is the path to your image.

Also try to add some random data to an image url like `?rand=3123131`. This should prevent browser from caching the image.

Comment: it isn't in THREE.Cache..... i try  texture/file.png?rand=43242 and don't work... i can return something like data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG..... but i don0t know how to load it in a texture var

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with this problem?